# Hide notification bar in service

Tags: android

I'm using following code to show view in my service, how can i disable/hide/prevention to open notification bar in my codes?

```
public void onStart(final Intent intent, final int n) 
{

    numIs = 1;
    this.view = ((LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService("layout_inflater")).inflate(R.layout.screen, (ViewGroup)null);
    this.windowManager = (WindowManager)this.getSystemService("window");
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams windowManagerLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    windowManagerLayoutParams.type = 2002;
    windowManagerLayoutParams.format = 1;
    windowManagerLayoutParams.flags = 40;
    windowManagerLayoutParams.height = -1;
    windowManagerLayoutParams.width = -1;
    this.windowManager.addView(this.view, (WindowManager.LayoutParams)windowManagerLayoutParams);      
}
```

Comment: if you show a view in your service, why don't you use an Activity?

Comment: For some reason i cannot say it :)
Please help me

Comment: any advice?please  help